# silverstripe installation error "silverstripe/vendor-plugin 1.3.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found"

Tags: installation, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am trying to install silverstripe but i am getting the following error. 
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
    - silverstripe/vendor-plugin 1.3.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - silverstripe/vendor-plugin 1.3.1 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for silverstripe/vendor-plugin 1.3.1 -> satisfiable by silverstripe/vendor-plugin[1.3.1].

please help to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fairly likely that you're using an older version of composer.

Update composer and try again:

```
composer selfupdate
composer install
```